# Interview-Style Short Story About Clone/Stand Ins for Interactions Where the Interviewee ends up being the Clone

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Looking for a short story that's framed as an interview with a journalist? Or clone-maker? About a society where everyone has a clone/stand in that they use to run small conversations with other people that will anticipate how the actual person wants to respond. They talk a lot about the convenience of it and the way that you can edit the clone's responses so that they sound more polished or more how you want to sound. The story is framed as a conversation with a real person, but at the end we see the real person editing the responses of their clone/stand in and saying something to the effect of "yeah, that's more like what I would say".